How to rename a function in .so file?
I have a library (libms.so) which contains a function Java_com_miar_cpo_Xml_makefile. I want to rename this function to Java_com_mypack_cls_Xml_makefile and save changes in .so file. I want only to rename function name so how to do that? This is for android native code reverse engineering. Thanks.
save changes in so file
